# jQuery/AJAX and SQL query not displaying html form inputs on browser permanently upon refreshing the browser?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to display all my textarea inputs in my browser (because if I refresh my page all data is gone from what i have sent through my html form using jquery/ajax ). So currently using jquery/ajax information from homepage.php is being sent to data.php through my #textarea input and returned on success to be displayed is my #status div. Every time i hit the POST button the data is added to the browser but when I refresh the page data is all lost ( even though the information is stored in my sql table). I understand i need to use a while() loop and I have tried but none of my code works in respect to what I am trying to achieve.

Homepage.php

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

session_start();


if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id'] != "") {

        $sid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id='{$sid}'";

 $query = $conn->query($sql);



$result = $query->fetch_assoc();


$fname = $result['fname'];

$lname = $result['lname'];

$time = time();


    }


      else {

        header("location:login.php");
    }

?>

<html>
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//daddy code
$ (document).ready(function() {

//mama code
$("button#postbutton").click(function() {

 var data = $("#formpost").serialize();
 var posterid = <?php echo $sid; ?>;

$.ajax({

type: "POST",

url: "data.php",

data: data,

success: function(data) {

$("#statustext").append(data);
$("textarea#text1").val('');
}

});



});



});



</script>
</head>

<body>


<div id="global">

<form id="formpost" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false">

<textarea id="text1" name="status" value="" ></textarea>


<button id="postbutton">POST</button>

<a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a>

</form>

<br/>
<br/>


<div id="allstatus">

<!-- SKELETON -->


<div id="wholestatus">


<div id="statuspic">
</div>


<div id="statusinfo">

<div id="statusname"><?php echo " Welcome to VLE, {$fname} {$lname} ";?></div>
<div id="statustext"> </div>


</div>


</div>  


<!-- SKELETON -->


</div>


</div>


</body>


</html>
```

data.php

```
<?php



const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
const DB_USER = 'root';
const DB_PASS = '';
const DB_NAME = 'forum';
//connecting 

$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {

 }


if(isset($_POST['status']))
{
$var = $_POST['status'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `question`(id, question) VALUES ('', '{$var}')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result) {  }

    else {

    echo "failed: " . $conn->error;
   }


echo  "<br>{$var}";



}





 ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+F5 or Ctrl+R to force a refresh? It might be that the output is cached in the browser. If this turns out to be the issue, you can set a header to tell the browser that it should not cache the page.

Comment: State doesn't really persist on the client so when you refresh you're basically starting over from scratch. And why are you doing page refreshes if you're using ajax anyways?

Comment: I just want to retrieve all data from sql table using a while loop that fetches assoc. The problem is my code wont work...my $var contains all textarea input and is stored in sql table question however when i refresh my browser the html display is gone. If you understand what I mean..

Comment: for example $query = "SELECT * FROM `question` ";
$result = $conn->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo  "<br>{$row['question']}";

} but this gone does not display my sql table the proper way.

Comment: That's the nature of browsers and refreshes. When you refresh, it has no memory of what you were doing before or what happened in the browser or on your page...so of course your HTML is gone. You need to query the database in the page so every time it loads you will see your results.  But like I already said, why are you depending/messing around with page refreshes when you're already using ajax? After you post, why refresh? Just display the results using the success function.

Comment: Yes i want to display my results of the question table on refresh. I am not sure of this success function. Can you show me how it is done?

Comment: i have the success function as when data is sent back to homepage.php but how can i use it to display my results?

Answer (score 0):

Your select is calling for a specific Session id but your insert is not storing anything inside id column.

Comment: it is set to auto increment and id is being stored in my sql table as i checked it

Comment: How is your Session id connected to this Auto incremented table id?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you keep talking about page refreshes if you're using ajax, because ajax allows you to send/retrieve data without a page refresh.

In your success function, anything that is returned is in your variable called `data`, but I bet if you looked at the contents of this variable you will see that it doesn't have anything because your `data.php` is not setup to give a proper response.

You need this in your `data.php` file...

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

And then when you echo the response, you need to do it like this...

```
echo json_encode($var);
```

Now within the success function your `data` will hold the contents of `$var` which is actually holding the contents of `$_POST['status']`.

So then within the success function you can display the results like this...

```
$('#statustext').html(data)
```

Comment: I understand,  guess I am doing everything wrong because I want to create a browser where users can post questions for others to see. So the fact that if i refresh my browser all the questions posted are gone (despite being in the database) is completely pointless.

Comment: What do you mean create a browser? And putting things into the database and retrieving things from the database is two separate steps. In  order for me to load a page and see what you put into the database, that page needs to contain the code that queries the database and gets that information.

Comment: yes thats using the while() loop but data is displayed when i click post. i want it to display regardless of the .click event

Comment: You're not using a while loop, so what are you talking about? And I don't think I can help you any further because I've explained everything that you need to know.